# Problem with Bezier Path Creator and Third Person Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier

I have a really strange problem. I have downloaded a "Bezier Path Creator" https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/b-zier-path-creator-136082 (code below):

```
﻿using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PathCreation
{
    public class PathCreator : MonoBehaviour
{

    /// This class stores data for the path editor, and provides accessors to get the current vertex and bezier path.
    /// Attach to a GameObject to create a new path editor.

    public event System.Action pathUpdated;

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    PathCreatorData editorData;
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    bool initialized;

    // Vertex path created from the current bezier path
    public VertexPath path
    {
        get
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                InitializeEditorData(false);
            }
            return editorData.vertexPath;
        }
    }

    // The bezier path created in the editor
    public BezierPath bezierPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                InitializeEditorData(false);
            }
            return editorData.bezierPath;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                InitializeEditorData(false);
            }
            editorData.bezierPath = value;
        }
    }

    #region Internal methods

    /// Used by the path editor to initialise some data
    public void InitializeEditorData(bool in2DMode)
    {
        if (editorData == null)
        {
            editorData = new PathCreatorData();
        }
        editorData.bezierOrVertexPathModified -= OnPathUpdated;
        editorData.bezierOrVertexPathModified += OnPathUpdated;

        editorData.Initialize(transform.position, in2DMode);
        initialized = true;
    }

    public PathCreatorData EditorData
    {
        get
        {
            return editorData;
        }

    }

    void OnPathUpdated()
    {
        if (pathUpdated != null)
        {
            pathUpdated();
        }
    }

    #endregion
    }
}
```

So it worked really nice, and I liked it. I used it for my tram system. But after it I needed to create a third person camera and I wrote such a code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraRotateAround : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public Vector3 offset;
public float sensitivity = 3;
public float limit = 80;
public float zoom = 0.25f;
public float zoomMax = 10; 
public float zoomMin = 3; 
private float X, Y;

void Start ()
{
    limit = Mathf.Abs(limit);
    if(limit > 90) limit = 90;
    offset = new Vector3(offset.x, offset.y, -Mathf.Abs(zoomMax)/2);
    transform.position = target.position + offset;
    offset.z -= zoom + 3;
}

void Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0) offset.z += zoom;
    else if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0) offset.z -= zoom;
    offset.z = Mathf.Clamp(offset.z, -Mathf.Abs(zoomMax), -Mathf.Abs(zoomMin));

    X = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
    Y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
    Y = Mathf.Clamp (Y, -limit, 0);
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-Y, X, 0);
    transform.position = transform.localRotation * offset + target.position;
}
}
```

And after it at first seconds of gameplay everything was nice, but that the camera started to fly away from the tram. I really don't have any idea what to do with it and why it is happening.

The video about flying camera away from the tram is there: https://youtu.be/BXHnvq8bpPM.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: hmm seems like the position of the camera is parented to and object which is not bound to the rotation of the train. Just a guess if you let the train go around the track completely its back in the proper spot when it make a full lap correct?

Comment: @johnny5 oh god, after the full lap camera it returning to a normal position. Also I tried to remove camera from tram, but then it started twitching and it's flying away from tram and it's not returning to normal position. Example: https://youtu.be/INJStzE2hew

Comment: @ГлебБуткевич Did johnny's suggestion solve your problem? If not, would you mind updating your question?

Comment: @DominikMokriš It didn't help me so much, I found the answer on my next question